# How to inject a value from a parent page to iframe (both are hosted on different domains)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Because the two pages are on different domains I have not been successful in passing the value to the iframe.

This doesn't work:

```
var source = document.getElementById('SourceValue').value = sourceCookie;
```

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you're attempting to add a cookie to the document of an iframe by either injecting an inline script or execute script on the parent. is that correct?  There is a sandbox attribute and permission related attributes that are to be defined on the iframe itself; but, I need you to clarify whether you're attempting to handle a session cookie in this manner.

Comment: @brettCaswell I am not attempting to handle a session, the cookie from the parent page is meant to pass the information about the browsing to the form in the iframe to be captured in the form submission